# hide an animated image by hovering another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image that is stuck with the mouse and I am moving around it, and there is another image which animated with jQuery, now if I put a stick image hover an animated image that needs to hide.
some sort of code that I have used, but didn't work

```
 $('#basketimg').mouseenter(function(){
 $('#my_img').stop().animate({top:'0px'})
 $('#my_img').hide(); 
 })
```

Comment: instead of mouseenter() try .hover() ; check this link: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: make your code in fiddle and provide link

Comment: @Praveen Could you please check your HTML code.. the Image control's `ID` are same as `basketimg` and `my_img`?

Comment: here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qC3WY/2/), ball is suppose to animate up and down but its not working in fiddle but its working in my project, consider ball is animating and and after select image once that image hover on ball, ball get disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$("#basketimg").hover(function () {
      $('#my_img').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
 }, function () {
      $('#my_img').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
 });
```

Thanks.

Comment: it didn't work, is there any code for hover? i mean if i select and image which is draggable and when this image put over another image, it generate an alert.